# How to insert angular directive dynamically on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a 2 directive help.js, cache.js where I have defined my directive code. Following are the html tags I am using to render them: `<div help></div>` & `<div cache></div>`

My directive code looks like this:

```js
/* Help.js */
app.directive("help", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    template: "<div>help</div>",
    controller: function(){}
  }
});

/* cache.js */
app.directive("cache", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    template: "<div>Cache</div>",
    controller: function(){}
  }
});
```

This works fine when I include them on a page like:

```js
<script src="help.js"></script>
<div help></div>
```

**What I need**
I need to pass a query string from page and based on that I will decide which directive to load. For e.g: I will pass myurl?param=help, it will load help.js and its html

**I tried this which didn't work on ie8:**

```js
var QueryParams = somefunctiontogetParamValue("param"); // will return help/cache

var scriptObj = document.createElement("script");
scriptObj.src = QueryParams + ".js"

$("body").append(scriptObj);

var reportDirective = document.createElement(QueryParams);
$("body").append(reportDirective);
```

Comment: You have to [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) all directives so that angular knows to process them.

Comment: Can you show me for my case how do I do that?

Comment: @DeepakRanjanJena does `help.js` have an angular code?